Ubuntu Core - legacy mode
I am trying to run Ubuntu Core on an IoT device with an i5 6th generation processor. Since this device doesn't have EFI, I must use legacy BIOS mode. I tried ready images and self-made ones, but whenever I try to run them, I get the message "Please boot in EFI mode." How can I build or write an image on a USB stick in legacy BIOS mode?
